# How can I Avoid XPC error with URLSession

Tags: swift, urlsession

In Xcode 14 / Swift I have created a new macOS Command Line Tool containing one file (main.swift) with three lines:

```
import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")

let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url!)
```

Running this program **usually** (but not always) generates a warning:

> [client] No error handler for XPC error: Connection invalid

Yet, the program seems to run successfully and the "data" object returned from URLSession.shared.data(from:) is valid -- that is, I can decode its contents and see the json contents.

Is there a way to avoid this XPC error?

*Edit: the error seems not to happen if I wait 30-60 seconds between runs.
*Edit2: actually, the error sometimes happens even if I do wait 30-60 seconds (or more) between runs.